# Capture printer output from device

Tags: c#, serial-port, desktop-application, printers

I am writing an application that needs to capture data sent from a device (a grain analyzer) to a printer.  The device's output port is a USB port, but the output is intended to go to a printer with a RS232 port.  I have a USB to RS232 (DB25) cable that works with the printer - I get printed output just fine.  What I want to do is capture that output in my application.  When I connect the device to my computer with a straight USB cable, or using any number of adapter combinations, the device will not print ("No Printer Found").

So apparently I need to somehow in my application make the computer look like a printer to the device, so I can capture the printed data.  I have been searching for help on this issue, and have found a number of questions loosely related, but have not found anything that solves my problem.

I am developing a Windows Desktop application (Windows 10) using C#.

Comment: The magic that makes the analyzer "see" a printer is most likely in the programmable chip of its USB-to-RS232 cable.  So use that with the analyzer, a USB-to-RS232 cable for your computer, and a null modem adapter to mate the two together.

Comment: Thank you Ben, I will try that.  The cable that I am using to connect the analyzer to an actual printer (which is working) is nothing special.  Not something that came with the instrument; just one I picked up at a local electronics store, so I don't know about there being any special programming in a chip of that cable.  One thing I have not yet tried, however, is your suggestion of connecting the two USB-to-DB25 cables via a null modem adapter, so I will try that and post the results here.  Thanks again.

Comment: If the USB-RS232 adapter isn't special, then the analyzer may be receiving responses from the printer.  In which case you'll want the printer connected normally, with a wiretap box on the RS-232 lines so your development environment can receive all the traffic.  You'd need two USB/serial adapters on your computer for that, both operating receive-only.  One receiving what the adapter transmits and the printer receives, one receiving what the printer transmits back to the adapter.

Comment: Once you see what the printer's response looks like, you can generate that response from software (with the USB - serial - null modem - serial - USB setup)

Comment: You can also use your computer as the wiretap box, like (analyzer - USB - serial - null modem - serial - USB - development PC - USB - serial - printer), and have software forward data between the two ports and log it all in the process.  However that's more fragile because you have to have all the baud rates and hardware handshaking set correctly and forwarding data and handshaking signals, before you will have a working conversation to snoop on.

Comment: Ben - I looked up some wire tap devices on line.  What I found was a device with three serial connections:  one goes to the device that's doing the printing; one goes to the printer; one goes to the computer to intercept (listen in).  I don't understand how I would connect two USB/Serial adapters to the computer.  Are there wiretap devices out there with 4 connectors?  Or are you suggesting some kind of configuration that uses two wire tap devices?  I'm a little lost here ...

Comment: https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/cable/rs-232-spy-monitor#full The full-duplex one is the one you're wanting.  I'll do a quick search and see if I see anything ready-made

Comment: Honestly a multipack of breakout adapters (https://www.amazon.com/Breakout-Serial-Female-Terminal-Adapter/dp/B077M2SJ2C) is probably your cheapest solution, you just need a few jumper wires.  4 of them make a sniffer, add the 5th wired as null-modem and now you don't need to disturb the sniffer setup to test your pretends-to-be-a-printer software.

Comment: (The null-modem connection will be identical to one of the tap ports, except that it also connects the pin transmitting data into the system for the other direction as well)

Comment: Only... I guess you might want to make one or more of the ports DB-25 instead of DB-9.  Preserve the names of the pins being connected for the wiretap diagram, not the pin numbers, if you do that.

Comment: Lots of options and lots to digest here, Ben.  Thank you very much for your patient assistance.

Answer (score 0):

With big thanks and all appropriate credit to Ben Voigt for his advice and help, I wanted to post this "answer" for the benefit of anyone else who might be dealing with this issue.

The solution for me was a cable from a company called CommFront called a "usb to RS-232 Adapter/converter":

https://www.commfront.com/products/usb-to-single-rs232-adapter-converter?variant=39593863086177

I also ordered a full duplex listening/monitoring cable from this company, but was unable to get it to work as expected.  In the process of trying every combination I could concoct, I tried the adapter/converter, and was able to capture the data just as it is sent to a printer.

============================ EDIT ==============================

Well, I'm not sure what is unclear in the above, but the community bot has asked for additional details to help with understanding, so in the interest of good citizenship, here goes:

My initial problem was that I could not read data from an instrument which had a USB output port, but which only communicated with a printer.  I could get the instrument to print just fine, but could not read any data from the cable into my computer.  After trying all kinds of different combinations of cables and adapters, the cable referenced above (which is called a USB to RS-232 Adapter/Converter) enabled me to read the data.  I believe whatever the "coverter" aspect of this cable is, made the instrument believe it was sending data to a printer, and I was able to capture the formatted data via a serial port.  The CommFront cable I referenced was USB-A on one end, and DB9 on the other end.  So I attached a plain (non-converter) DB9-to-USB cable to it, and plugged the USB end into my laptop.  The laptop recognized this as a serial device and could read data from it.  Works like a charm.

Hope this is helpful to others along the way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).